# Universal Video Class - how to switch off AGC

Tags: uvc

I have UVC running correctly with a camera. I can control the brightness and contrast fine with:

```
MedCap.VideoDeviceController.Brightness.TrySetValue(pbrightness)
MedCap.VideoDeviceController.Contrast.TrySetValue(pcontrast)
```

The camera seems to have an AGC feature, such that if the view becomes darker, it steps up the brightness level automatically. I would like to prevent this, I want the brightness level to be manual only.

There seem to be many properties of VideoDeviceController, is this in there somewhere?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer:

```
MedCap.VideoDeviceController.WhiteBalance.TrySetAuto(False)
MedCap.VideoDeviceController.Exposure.TrySetAuto(False)
```